# Cómo hacer binding a una consulta SQLite

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, sqlite3, binding

Quiero hacer **binding** de los datos de una tabla SQLite a un listView pero quiero hacerlo desde mi viewModel, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? Gracias.

Comment: Hola @EdwinV, mira te recomiendo que agregues un poco mas de datos, como por ejemplo que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora y que no te funciona, ya que asi es probable que cierren tu pregunta, te dejo un [link de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hola @EdwinV, añade más información sobre lo que tratas de hacer, el código que tienes hasta el momento, lo que has intentado, lo que has investigado etc para que algún usuario pueda ayudarte. Te recomiendo leer: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @EdwinV pudiste implementar mis sugerencias?

Comment: @JuanK si lo he implementado y funciona correctamente muchas gracias pero tengo una duda cual es la ventaja de instalar el paquete .VSIX que me recomiendas?

Comment: es la integración completa con VS, lo cual permite por ejemplo que cuando hayan updates visual studio te avise

Comment: Siempre es un gusto ayudar ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, esta es mi forma preferida, como no has colocado nada de código (deberías hacerlo en el futuro para facilitar las cosas a quienes te queremos ayudar) he creado esta pequeña solución.

Deber agregar este paquete de **Nuget** (hay muchas opciones de SQLite)
 - SQLite.Net-PCL

Y por comodidad te recomiendo adicionar esta extensión de VS

- [sqlite-uap-3100000.vsix](http://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-uap-3100000.vsix) : VSIX package for Universal App Platform development using Visual Studio 2015

### modelo

[Puedes Obtener aquí **BindableBase** si aún no lo tienes](https://juank.io/apps-binding-inotifypropertychanged-bindablebase-xaml-c/)

```
public class User : BindableBase
{
    private int _id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
    }

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }
}
```

### viewmodel

he escogido hacer inicialización perezosa del viewmodel, para poder crear una instancia del viewmodel desde **xaml** y aún así asegurarme de que el viewmodel es inicializado. El método Initialize se encarga de la inicialización (un poco obvio). Para ahorrarte problemas he usado adicionalmente un interbloqueo para evitar errores de concurrencia.

```
public class MainAppVM : BindableBase
{

    private bool _initialized = false;
    private object _lockject = new object();
    private User _firstUser;


    public User FirstUser
    {
        get
        {
            Initialize();

            return _firstUser;
        }
        set
        {SetProperty(ref _firstUser, value);}
    }

    private List<User> _userList;

    public List<User> UserList
    {
        get
        {
            Initialize();
            return _userList;
        }
        set
        {SetProperty(ref _userList, value);}
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {

        lock (_lockject)
        {
            if (!_initialized)
            {
                _initialized = true;
                var path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");

                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path))
                {
                    var list = from user in conn.Table<User>()
                               select user;

                    this._firstUser = list.FirstOrDefault();
                    this._userList = list.ToList();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## xaml

fijate en la línea #6 que comienza con `xmlns:vm` allí he referenciado el namespace de donde tengo el viewmodel.

Luego instancio el viewmodel como datacontext

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainAppVM></vm:MainAppVM>
</Page.DataContext>
```

Y después ya todo lo resuelvo con el binding.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:vm="using:App3.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="Page_Loaded"
    >
    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MainAppVM></vm:MainAppVM>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"  />
            <RowDefinition  Height="4*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>First Result:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstUser.Name}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView  Grid.Row="1" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding UserList, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Y listo! eso es todo, en mi caso he adicionado algo en el MainPage.xaml.cs para sembrar datos de prueba tras cada ejecución:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loading += MainPage_Loading;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loading(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");

        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<User>();

            conn.Insert(new User() { Name = "Random " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        }
    }
```

### Descarga de [aqui el ejemplo completo](http://1drv.ms/1W8btth)